# steam is not in the sudoers file error when Installing steamcmd on fresh ubuntu server 22.04 LTS

Tags: server, sudo, steam

While attempting to setup a valheim dedicated server on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-39-generic x86_64)

I am trying to run these instructions to install steamcmd:

Create a user account named steam to run SteamCMD safely, isolating it from the rest of the operating system.
Warning:Do not run steamcmd while operating as the root user. Doing so is a security risk.

1. As the root user, create the steam user:

```
sudo useradd -m steam
sudo passwd steam
```

2. Go into its home folder:

```
sudo -u steam -s
cd /home/steam
```

Package From Repositories

1. It's recommended to install the SteamCMD package from your distribution repositories, if available:
   Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt install steamcmd
```

----Here is a copy of what happens----

```
server@ubuntu:~$ sudo useradd -m steam
[sudo] password for server: 
useradd: user 'steam' already exists
server@ubuntu:~$ sudo passwd steam
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
server@ubuntu:~$ sudo -u steam -s
steam@ubuntu:/home/server$ cd /home/steam
steam@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install steamcmd
[sudo] password for steam: 
steam is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

at this point forward i have different results trying to resolve the error

I understand steam needs root acces and it needs to be added somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is sudo complaining about is that steam is not in the sudo group so
run this on a user where sudo works `sudo adduser steam sudo`

- `sudo` get root previges
- `adduser` used for adding users and adding user to groups for more info run `adduser --help`
- `steam` the user to add to the group
- `sudo` the group to add the user

Why does this happen?
Well, it's a security feature to allow some user to use sudo, but others do not.
Note the `/etc/sudoers` sets rules for sudo, but I do not recmend to edit it

Hope that answered your question and welcome to ask Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you , im happy to be here!